# Create Defect / task specific to User story using Java Rally Rest API

Tags: java, rest, rally

How to create a defect / task to a user story Using java Rally-Rest-API. Also can anyone have the link where the attributes for the rally query is available?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an introduction to the Java REST API here:

https://developer.help.rallydev.com/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api

And documentation on Rally's Webservices API here:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice

To create a new Defect and associate it to a story you would do something like this:

```
// Query for Story to associate with Defect
String storyFormattedID = "US20142";
QueryRequest storyRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name","Changesets"));
storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", storyFormattedID));
QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);
JsonObject storyJsonObject = storyQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
String storyRef = storyJsonObject.get("_ref").toString();

JsonObject newDefect = new JsonObject();
newDefect.addProperty("Name", "Test Defect");
newDefect.addProperty("Priority", "High Attention");
newDefect.addProperty("Severity", "Major Problem");
newDefect.addProperty("Requirement", storyRef);

CreateRequest storyCreateRequest = new CreateRequest("defect", newDefect);
CreateResponse storyCreateResponse = restApi.create(storyCreateRequest);
```

The process for a Task would be very similar:

```
// Create a new Task and associate to the same Requirement
JsonObject newTask = new JsonObject();
newTask.addProperty("Name", "Test Task");
newTask.addProperty("State", "Defined");
newDefect.addProperty("WorkProduct", storyRef);

CreateRequest taskCreateRequest = new CreateRequest("task", newTask);
CreateResponse taskCreateResponse = restApi.create(taskCreateRequest);
```